# how to access User and UserProfile in TemplateView

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

User Model is inbuilt auth table and UserProfile Model is extended OneToOneField. Now i am get user_company from url which is stored in UserProfile but i also want data from User Model also. The bellow code i am trying but it gives error `type object 'User' has no attribute 'UserProfile'`

```
User.UserProfile.objects.filter(user_company=id_)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
User.objects.filter(userprofile__user_company=id_)
```

Reference can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/#one-to-one-relationships).